# How can I quickly farm Key Fragments?

Tags: destiny-2

I am working on collecting the Escalation Protocol armour set for my Triumph. To do this I need to collect 7 key fragments to hand into Ana Bray for an Encrypted Cache Key.

Ref: https://www.tldrgames.com/guide/destiny-2-warmind/destiny-2-encrypted-cache-key-guide/

> Once you have finished the main story missions of the Warmind DLC, you can begin to do Heroic Strikes, Heroic Adventures, Nightfall Strikes and the Raid. Successfully completing any of these has the chance to drop a Rasputin Key Fragment. Once per week, you can hand in these Key Fragments to Ana Bray, and she will give you an Encrypted Cache Key. Each Key needs seven Key Fragments.

What is the fastest way to collect the 7 required fragments, ideally whilst knocking off daily bounties as well.

Comment: I did a Nightfall and got 7 Fragments, so that's a nice way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing a Nightfall Strike will reward 7 Key Fragments. I have received this as a reward twice now.

So Nightfalls are an effective way of getting all 7 fragments at once.